# iPhone core data migration date to string

Tags: iphone, core-data, migration, mapping-model

I have an entity that originally started with a date attribute. I have now added a attribute that is a string that I want to hold the date, in addition to keeping the original field.
I've made a mapping model, but I'm not sure what to put into "value expression" to get the new string field filled with data from the date field in the format "2010-10-25" during migration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also I need it to be a real attribute not a transient because I want to sort on it. I didn't realize you couldn't sort on transient attribute until too late.

Comment: You want to sort on the date string representation, not the date itself?

Comment: I just need the new text field filled in during migration from the existing date field. The app already uses it, I just need to hook up people with older version of the app to migrate their existing core data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating the property from a date to a string is going to require that you build your own `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` for that migration and override the `-createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance: entityMapping: manager: error:` method to handle the translation.

This should be very straight forward code since you are only going to be manipulating a couple of properties and the entity mapping is still one to one.